# Trying to use GAM to check for a Google Drive folder that's been created/modified in last 30 days

Tags: google-drive-api

We're using GAM to try and audit clients' Google Drives, specifically their My Drives; we want to make sure they're backing up Desktop and Documents, and check to see if those two folders exist and have been used in the past 30 days.

This is the command we're trying to implement:

`gam user user@domain.com print filelist id title mimetype query "'root' in parents and title = 'Desktop' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and modifiedTime > '2024-01-01T12:00:00'"`

However, it's returning "invalid query." It *does *work if we remove the modifiedTime query option; but it's strange, because that last piece is still correct syntax. Any thoughts?